# Mutate columns conditional on other columns in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe that has many columns describing the number of a particular asset that a household owns. I would like set all missing values `NA` equal to 0 conditional on there being at least one non `NA` value in at least one other `asset_` column. For example, in the dataframe:

```
dat <- data.frame(asset_1 = c(NA, 2, NA), asset_2 = c(1,3,NA), asset_3 = c(NA, NA, NA))
```

| asset_1 | asset_2 | asset_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NA | 3 | NA |
| 0 | 1 | NA |
| NA | NA | NA |

I would to achieve:

| asset_1 | asset_2 | asset_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| NA | NA | NA |

Is there any nice way to do this with Dplyr? Any more efficient alternatives in any other package are also welcome.

My guess would be to use `mutate` in combination with `across` and `if_else` but I can't figure out a way to consider all columns except the one that is being mutated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(asset_1 = c(NA, 2, NA), asset_2 = c(1,3,NA), asset_3 = c(NA, NA, NA))
dat2 <- dat %>% mutate(new=coalesce(asset_1,asset_2,asset_3), across(starts_with('asset'), ~ ifelse(!is.na(new) & is.na(.x), 0, .x))) %>% dplyr::select(-new)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  mutate(helper = apply(across(everything()), 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x))),
         across(-helper, ~ifelse(helper != 3 & is.na(.), 0, .)))

  asset_1 asset_2 asset_3 helper
1       0       1       0      2
2       2       3       0      1
3      NA      NA      NA      3
```

Comment: Thanks you! This also works perfectly but @jkatam's answer is a little bit cleaner when dealing with many columns.